# Time tracking app for mac w/ special requirements

Tags: osx, time-management

I'm looking for a time tracking app for mac with the following features:

- it constantly reminds me, if I have not activated any task.
- it follows a pomodoro technique: tracks by discrete 30 min time
  intervals.
- it can fetch tasks from popular 3rd party TODO apps, like Wunderlist, Todoist, etc.

The first requirement is the most important. Because I often find myself working without any enabled tracking project/task.